# how to change textbox text in client side with c# script

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is that possible to change the textbox text in the client side with `c# script`(Not javascript). Here is what I tried, but it doesn't work:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Dis" runat="server">Old text</asp:TextBox>

<%Dis.Text = "New Text"; %>
```

Comment: C# executes at server. You must use JS to do anything in the client side.

Comment: @Fals I know how to do it with `JS`, I wrote some C# script at the client side, it works, but changing the textbox text doesn't work.

Comment: @ZhenxiaoHao as I have written in my ansewr the C# code is executed on the server and then the resulting html page goes to the client's web browser. That being said, you can't have execution of C# code in client side.

Comment: @ZhenxiaoHao You're confusing your concepts here. What you did was write it on the aspx page. This does not mean you wrote it "client-side". It will still execute on the server.

Comment: @Ben Black Alright, now I'm clear, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not possible. C# is used for writing the server side code in web applications -when we have to do with web apps. I point out this because C# can be used to build almost everything. Whatever has to do with the client, you have to programm it in plain javascript or using a javascript framework. As far as how you will change the text of your textbox, it depends on when you want to do so. I mean which will be the event, which will trigger this change. If you specify this, I could post here some code to show you how you can achieve this.

**UPDATE**

When you refer to C# script, you possibly refer to the C# code we sometimes write inside our html pages using `<% %>`. Yeah, in this respect you can say that C# scripts exist. However, this code runs at the server, and then the created html page goes from the server to the client.

Comment: Okay, thanks, but there do exist `C# script`, right?

Comment: Yes, C# script exists, but it is not a web scripting technology like javascript. It is a desktop scripting language like batch or vb-script. For reference: http://www.csscript.net/

Answer (score 1):

Only using ajax request which is clearly not your requirement.

Comment: Is it possible to do it with ajax?